# AWS - Jenkins - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I would like to use Jenkins in Ec2 Instance. I followed this link : https://d0.awsstatic.com/Projects/P5505030/aws-project_Jenkins-build-server.pdf to configure it.

Then I added a group for my instance and allow access to "80" (http), "8080" (jenkins), "22" (ssh).

When I open my browser and want to open my instance with my DNS  "http://:8080", I get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Anyone can help me please ?

Here my security group :[image]

Thank you in advance,

Djoh

Comment: provide your security group screen-shot and is trafic on 8080 is allowed from anywhere ?

Comment: @AmitK I put the screen-shot. The trafic is allow from anywhere on 8080

Answer (score 0):

That's fine. I finally open a new instance with Ubuntu and everything works correctly. Thank you for everything by the way.

Djoh